# Show single result for duplicates from columns and include remaining table results

Tags: sql, duplicates

Is there a way to show distinct results from columns which contain the same duplicate result and to show this with the remaining results?

I would like to show one result from the traderid column, one result from the contactid column and continue showing the remaining column results for communicationmethodid, contact & destination.

Is this possible?

I'm using SSMS 2014

My Query Example:

select

```
contactcommunications.traderid, 
contactcommunications.contactid, 
contactcommunications.communicationmethodid, 
contactcommunications.destination, contactcommunications.tradertype,
contactcommunications.communicationmethodid + ' '+ 
contactcommunications.countrycode + ' ' + 
contactcommunications.areacode + ' ' + 
contactcommunications.localnumber AS contactnumber,
tradercommunications.traderid As tradercommtraderid, 
tradercommunications.addressid, 
tradercommunications.street, tradercommunications.city, 
tradercommunications.county, 
tradercommunications.postcode, tradercommunications.countryid, 
tradercommunications.telephonenumber, 
tradercommunications.telephonenumber2,
tradercommunications.faxnumber, 
tradercommunications.mobiletelephonenumber,
suppliercontacts.firstname, suppliercontacts.lastname, 
CASE WHEN suppliercontacts.mainaddressid = 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END 
As MainAddID, 
CASE WHEN suppliercontacts.ismainaddresscontact = 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 
'NO' END As MainContact

FROM

contactcommunications

LEFT OUTER JOIN tradercommunications ON 
tradercommunications.tradertype = 'S'
AND tradercommunications.traderid = contactcommunications.traderid

LEFT OUTER JOIN suppliercontacts ON suppliercontacts.supplier = 
contactcommunications.traderid
AND contactcommunications.contactid = suppliercontacts.contactid

WHERE contactcommunications.tradertype ='S'

AND contactcommunications.traderid = 'SOX01'

ORDER BY

contactcommunications.contactid,
contactcommunications.destination, contactcommunications.tradertype,
contactcommunications.communicationmethodid + ' ' + 
contactcommunications.countrycode + ' ' + 
contactcommunications.areacode + ' ' + 
contactcommunications.localnumber,
tradercommunications.traderid, tradercommunications.addressid,
tradercommunications.street, tradercommunications.city, 
tradercommunications.county,
tradercommunications.postcode, tradercommunications.countryid,
tradercommunications.telephonenumber, 
tradercommunications.telephonenumber2,
tradercommunications.faxnumber, 
tradercommunications.mobiletelephonenumber,
suppliercontacts.firstname, suppliercontacts.lastname
DESC
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: What DBMS you are using ? What query that you have created ? Did you stuck somewhere ?

Comment: I've updated the question